# JPA Webapp in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jpa

We are running into "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named persistence.xml" Exception while setting up a basic web application in tomcat.

We are using eclipselink as the JPA Provider and the JPA is created as a separate project and the jar is included in the WEB-INF/lib folder of web application.

The WAR when deployed contains the jar within the WEB-INF/lib folder and the persistence.xml is present within the META-INF folder of the jar.

Any clues on how to overcome this issue is much appreciated.

Below is the stack trace,

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named persistence.xml
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at com.abc.servlet.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:38)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The persistence.xml looks like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.poc.Person</class>
        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="MASKED"/>           
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="MASKED"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="MASKED"/>
            <property name="eclipelink.logging.level" value="DEBUG"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode " value="sql-script"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="ALL"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>  
            <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>        
        </properties>               
    </persistence-unit> 
</persistence>
```

And attempting to deploy on Tomcat 9 ( I found the similar issue on Tomcat 7 & 8 ) as well. The version of eclipse link jar is 2.5.0

Comment: Show your code. Show the persistence.xml file.

Comment: Edited the question with persistence.xml file.

Comment: Your persistence unit is named persistence, not persistence.xml

Comment: Thats right. but the issue is it is unable to find the persistence.xml file itself though it is present in the classpath

Comment: If only you posted your code...

Comment: "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named persistence.xml", so you have put the wrong name in the line of code for getting hold of the EntityManagerFactory/EntityManager (as JBNizet told you), and you don't post the line of code that tries to create the EMF/EM. Good luck with that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of xerces*.jar that was present in the classpath along with Javax.persistence*.jar and eclipselink*.jar files. Because of the xerces*.jar files, the persistence.xml file couldn't be parsed and complained about non-existence of the file, though it was present.

Hopefully this helps someone.